# Finding Reference Angles in Precalculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, pi

I'm reviewing for an exam, and having some trouble with reference angles depending on the quadrant they lie in. For example, my book shows the following:

[image: RefAngle]

I get the part about subtracting 12pi/6, but what I'm having issues with is deciding whether to add or subtract when the angle is NOT in quadrant IV.

For example:

[image: RefAngle2]

Based on the book's other example, I would subract `12pi/6` from `31pi/6` until I get a result less than `12pi/6`.

31 - 12 = 19

19 - 12 = 7

`7pi/6` I believe would lie in Quadrant III, as `2pi` is a full rotation, and `1pi` is half, and `7pi/6` is a little over 1/2.

My question though, is compared to Quadrant IV, do I know subtract or add `7pi/6` to `12pi/6`?

Being Quadrant III I figured I would still subtract, resulting in `12pi/6 - 7pi/6 = 5pi/6` but apparently the correct answer is `pi/6`???

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: So they teach you to repeatedly subtract $2\pi$? I wonder what they'd suggest you do if you had an angle like $5000\pi / 6$?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not quite sure. My best guess at this point is that we will not be asked on any of the work to work with an angle of that magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the angle at or below $2\pi$ the reference angle is just the  angle $0\le x\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ that is the distance between your angle and the x axis.

So in quadrant I it is just x.

Quadrant II it is $\pi -x$

Quadrant III it is $x-\pi$

Quadrant IV it is $2\pi - x$

Some example reference angles in degrees...

30 is 30.  90 is 90.  95 is 85.  150 is 30.  190 is 10.  350 is 10.  Just think of the unit circle and figure out how big the angle is between your angle and the x axis.  The red angles in the image below.

[image]

Comment: So in my example above where I end up with `7pi/6`, since it is in Q3, I would do `7pi/6 - pi`??

Comment: Yep.  $7\pi/6$ goes past the -x axis by $\pi/6$.  Similar to example 3 in the image above.  ($\pi$ is the -x axis)

Comment: So basically it's all about finding how far *off* the angle is from the `x-axis`?

Comment: Exactly.  The smallest angle between it and the x-axis.  So, no matter how big the angle is, as it winds around and around the coordinate plane, it can never be more than $\pi/2$ from the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

In quadrant III, subtract $\pi$ from the value.

In quadrant II, subtract the value from $\pi$.

You don't need to subtract anything if it's in quadrant I!

Note: I may have misunderstood the question - I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: So Quadrant I don't subtract anything. Q2 subtrac from `pi`. Q3 subtract from `3pi/2`, and Q4 subtract from `12pi/2`. But WHY is this? Like, how exactly do you KNOW these values are what to subtract from? Sorry, I just feel like I've got one last gear in my head that isn't quite turning yet.

Comment: In quadrant 3 you subtract $\pi$ from your angle.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic why? It's because those angles are the quadrant borders. The angle $\pi$ is between quadrants II and III, and pi/2 is between I and II.

Comment: Also, you should look at a unit circle. You will see the values with similar coordinates. The reference angles of those values is the one in the first quadrant. A unit circle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#/image/File:Unit_circle_angles_color.svg